# groovy script to compare dates as quarters string values

Tags: regex, groovy, jira

I am trying to create a groovy script to compare two "date" strings,

** updated the code based on feedback*

I think this code works ok, However, just the rigidity of the code means that it will probably break - wondering if there were a more elegant solution to this?

```
static def getQtrInt(int Yr, int Qtr) {
    def baseYr = 2010
    println "current year: " + Yr
    int  diff = Yr - baseYr
    diff = diff * 4 
    diff = diff + Qtr
    return diff
   } 

def vals = ["FY22 Q4","FY23 Q2"]

def str1 = vals[0]
def str2 = vals[1]

println "string1: " + str1
//println "string2: " + str2

def yr1 = str1.substring(2,4) as Integer
def yr2 = str2.substring(2,4) as Integer

def q1 = str1.substring(6,7) as Integer
def q2 = str2.substring(6,7) as Integer

def x = getQtrInt(("20"+ yr1) as int, q1)
def y = getQtrInt(("20"+ yr2) as int, q2)

println y-x
```

thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: "the difference between FY21 Q3 and FY21 Q1 should = 3" - Presumably then the diff between Q2 and Q1 would then be 2 and the diff between Q1 and Q1 would be 1.  Is that the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be:

```
def data = ["FY22 Q2","FY22 Q3","FY21 Q3","FY21 Q4","FY21 Q1","FY21 Q2","FY22 Q1","FY22 Q4"]

def res = data.sort{ it - 'FY' - ' Q' }

assert res.toString() == '[FY21 Q1, FY21 Q2, FY21 Q3, FY21 Q4, FY22 Q1, FY22 Q2, FY22 Q3, FY22 Q4]'
```

Comment: Is the idea that this addresses "the difference between FY21 Q3 and FY21 Q1 should = 3" because after the sort the list you would then go find where the entries are in the sorted list, subtract the lower index from the higher index and then add 1?

Comment: No, this is actually only applying the difference between 2 values, i should not have put the array there, however, i like the sort function you recommend.